# Calculating probability of an event involving two normally distributed random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

I have two normally distributed, independent random variables $S^{(1)}$ and $S^{(2)}$:
$$S^{(1)} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2),\ S^{(2)} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$$

Given two positive real numbers, $a_i$ and $a_j$, I need to calculate the probability of the event

$$ S^{(1)} \ge a_i\ \land\ (S^{(1)} - a_i > S^{(2)} -a_j) $$

Any clue about how I could achieve this? My main difficulty is that the two sub-events I am composing are not independent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function

Comment: Do you need an analytical solution? If not, it doesn't seem difficult to numerically compute the integral (in R, for example).

Comment: I used Montecarlo estimation to calculate the value, but an analytical solution would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $X$, $Y$, $a_1$, and $a_2$ for $S^{(1)}$, $S^{(2)}$, $a_i$, and $a_j$, and writing $F_X$ and $F_Y$ for the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$:

$$\begin{align*}
P(X ≥ a_1 \text{ and } X - a_1 ≥ Y - a_2)
&= P(X ≥ a_1) P(X - a_1 ≥ Y - a_2 | X ≥ a_1) \\
&= (1 - F_X(a_1) P(X - Y ≥ a_1 - a_2 | X ≥ a_1) \\
&= (1 - F_X(a_1) [P(X - Y ≥ a_1 - a_2 | X ≥ a_1, Y < a_2) P(Y < a_2) +  P(X - Y ≥ a_1 - a_2 | X ≥ a_1, Y ≥ a_2) P(Y ≥ a_2)] \\
&= (1 - F_X(a_1) [F_Y(a_2) + (1 - F_Y(a_2)) P(X - Y ≥ a_1 - a_2 | X ≥ a_1, Y ≥ a_2)] .
\end{align*}$$

The last equality works because when $X ≥ a_1$ and $Y < a_2$, $X - Y ≥ a_1 - a_2$ follows algebraically.

This is a closed-form solution with the exception of the expression $P(X - Y ≥ a_1 - a_2 | X ≥ a_1, Y ≥ a_2)$, which can be thought of as a call to the CDF of the difference of two one-sided truncated normal distributions. Expressing this CDF in terms of $F_X$ and $F_Y$ or the standard normal CDF would likely be extremely messy (if it is even possible to evaluate all the integrals analytically), given two answers ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122198/14076), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/832982/343628)) by wolfies on other problems involving truncated normals.